# Running Clerk on NestJs is it possible?

Tags: nestjs, clerk

Is it possible to use Clerk on NestJs? I have been unable to find any documentation towards this. If it is possible and anyone has examples, please feel welcome to share.

Thanks

Comment: You'd use their [`nodejs` API and SDK](https://clerk.com/docs/references/nodejs/overview) inside the NestJS application. After all, a NestJS server is a NodeJS server at the end of the day.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel yes but how do you set it up as a nestjs module with authguard etc?

Comment: Asking to "make an authguard" is a pretty big thing. Easier would be to explain what you're having trouble understanding about how to integrate their SDK and show what you've tried so far

Answer (score 1):

nestjs is a nodejs framework

so anything you can do in nodejs is possible in nestjs.

Follow Clerk nodejs's docs and you should be fine

Comment: Would you please be able to provide an example of creating an AuthGuard with it? And or a module etc... The documentation is not very good

Comment: I don't know Clerk so I'm in the same boat as you. Shouldn't be hard, tho. The guard will just receive some data from the request and perform a checking over it or something like that, and return `true` or `false`

Answer (score 1):

Clerk’s node sdk should be enough to create a strategy and authguard in Nest. An authguard is just a piece of middleware that implements a strategy you define. Essentially you capture the jwt that you should be sending in the header (Bearer) to each request on your api.

I have used the Clerk-node-sdk in a project with a GraphQL Yoga server and it was pretty straight forward. Clerk has a validate function on their SDK which is what you will use in your Nest SDK to validate the jwt being sent from your frontend. I’d start there and work within a strategy with Nest.

Answer (score 0):

in app.controller.ts :

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get()
  async getClientList() {
    return await this.appService.getClientList();
  }
}
```

in app.service.ts :

```
import { Injectable} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Clerk } from '@clerk/clerk-sdk-node';

@Injectable()

    export class AppService {
      private clerkClient;

      constructor() {
        this.clerkClient = Clerk({
          secretKey: 'sk_test_yourApiKey',
        });
      }
    
      async getClientList() {
        return await this.clerkClient.users.getUserList();
      }
    }
```

in app.module.ts :

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

then start ur server and go to your localhost : me is http://localhost:3002/ but http://localhost:3000/ by default and adapt to your route me for this moment i have just app.service.ts i don't have created route yet